# How to restart the animation of a particle system?

Tags: particles

I create an expulsion so my particle system has the following settings:

End frame = Start frame + 1

I mean the value of the end frame is one frame larger than the value of the start frame.

Life time = 6

velocity = 8

Those settings create an expulsion starting from the start frame. What if I need this expulsion to start at frames 10, 50 and 100? Is it possible to Restart the expulsion?

I can't animate the start frame or the life time. Animating the number of particles doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need (3) separate Particle settings for that, like so:

[image]

Also a gif:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much  for the answer :)